# How to Repeat a Pattern in Spacy

Tags: pattern-matching, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to write a Spacy pattern to match names of authors. E.g., "Smith, John, Jones, Bob". But the comma can be a semicolon. I think the pattern I want is:

```
author_pattern = [
    {"IS_ALPHA": True},
    {"IS_ALPHA": True},
    {"IS_PUNCT": True}]
```

Except I want to say that pattern can repeat one or more times. I know how to make an element in a pattern "one or many" but not for a pattern itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match one or more of the same pattern you can use the "OP"-key and the "+" operator.

see here for an example and the official documentation:
https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#example2